# Merge array in array, into array above

Tags: php

In PHP I have an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attr_1] => value
                    [attr_2] => value
                    [attr_3] => value
                    [other_array] => Array
                        (
                            [attr_4] => value
                            [attr_5] => value
                            [attr_6] => value
                        )
                    [attr_7] => value
                    [attr_8] => value
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attr_1] => value
                    [attr_2] => value
                    [attr_3] => value
                    [other_array] => Array
                        (
                            [attr_4] => value
                            [attr_5] => value
                            [attr_6] => value
                        )
                    [attr_7] => value
                    [attr_8] => value
                )
        )
)
```

Probably very simple but it can't get it to work.. I want to merge the `other_array` into the array above so the output would become:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attr_1] => value
                    [attr_2] => value
                    [attr_3] => value
                    [attr_4] => value
                    [attr_5] => value
                    [attr_6] => value
                    [attr_7] => value
                    [attr_8] => value
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attr_1] => value
                    [attr_2] => value
                    [attr_3] => value
                    [attr_4] => value
                    [attr_5] => value
                    [attr_6] => value
                    [attr_7] => value
                    [attr_8] => value
                )
        )
)
```

Is there a PHP function for this, or a other quick way to achieve this?

Comment: There's no function except `array_merge`

Comment: Or `array_merge_recursive`, try something :)

Comment: A combination of `array_map` and `function()use(){}` wrapped into a recursive function can do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to `unset()` the `'other_array'`, so one way:

```
foreach($array['items'] as &$v) {
    $v = array_merge($v, $v['other_array']);
    unset($v['other_array']);
}
```

Comment: Does what I need. Thank you!